# How to use Selenium check the checkbox lists?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Hey StackOverflow community. I am very new to the web-scraping. I would like to scrape data from : [Click here for link](http://www.ncsl.org/research/elections-and-campaigns/ballot-measures-database.aspx) this website after selected "**all states", "all topics" and year "2017**" from the **checkboxes**. But I couldn't let selenium.webdriver to realize this action. I use the following codes copied from StackOverflow:

```
wd = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=curr_path+'/geckodriver')
wd.get(my_url)

for i in range(10):
    try:
        wd.find_element_by_id('dnn_ctr78525_BallotMeasuresDB_ckBxAllStates').click()
        break
    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        print('retry in 1s.')
        time.sleep(1)
```

The error is: `ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <input id="dnn_ctr78525_BallotMeasuresDB_ckBxAllStates" name="dnn$ctr78525$BallotMeasuresDB$ckBxAllStates" type="checkbox"> is not clickable at point (84.5,679.2666625976562) because another element <div id="psCookieSlider"> obscures it`

Then I tried this:

```
Create = wd.find_element_by_xpath("//*['dnn_ctr78525_BallotMeasuresDB_ckBxAllStates']")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until_not(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "psCookieSlider")))
Create.click()
```

The error popped out is like this: **BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe**

I need your suggestions and help. Thank you so much!

Comment: You will have to scroll down after opening the web site to proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'D:/Automation/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://www.ncsl.org/research/elections-and-campaigns/ballot-measures-database.aspx")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30) 

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 450)") 

all_state = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[text()='All States']/preceding-sibling::input")))
all_state.click()

all_topics = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[text()='All Topics']/preceding-sibling::input")))
all_topics.click()

year = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.divBottomInterior>select[id*='BallotMeasuresDB_ddlYear']"))
year.select_by_visible_text("2017")
```

and after that if you want to click on search button, you can follow this code :

```
search_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Search")))
search_button.click()
```

Comment: That works like a charm. Thank you so much for your help!